# setter methods for arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

I have a review class that I used to create an array in another class called game info.

I have created a setter method that is used to add a review to gameInfo's array of reviews. I have the `addReview` function to search through this games reviews and if there is an empty review slot, then add the review input into the reviews array. I just want to be sure that I have the logic correct for the `addReview` method.

```
class Review {
    //review class variables
    public String reviewText;
    public int numberOfStars;

    //review class constructor
    public Review(String reviewText, int numberOfStars) {
        this.reviewText=reviewText;
        this.numberOfStars=numberOfStars;
    }
}

class GameInfo {
    //game info class variables
    private String title;
    private Review[] reviews = new Review[10];

    //game info class constructor
    public GameInfo(String title, Review[] reviews) {
        this.title=title;
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    //setter to add single review to reviews[]
    public void addReview(Review r) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < this.reviews.length; i++)    {
            if(this.reviews[i] == null) {
                this.reviews[i].reviewText = r.reviewText;
                this.reviews[i].numberOfStars = r.numberOfStars;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: T.J.'s answer shows why this code will get an exception.  But I also question whether this is really how you want to do things.  To make your solution work, the code that constructs a `GameInfo` will also have to build an array of `null` slots that then get added later, or maybe an array with some reviews and a bunch of other `null` slots.  This seems like a C way of doing things.  Please look into `ArrayList` which is a much nicer way to allow for adding elements to an array dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to be sure that I have the logic correct for the addReview method.

No, two problems:

1. You have it looking for `null`, but then trying to assign to fields on that `null`:

   ```
   if(this.reviews[i] == null) {
       this.reviews[i].reviewText = r.reviewText; 
       this.reviews[i].numberOfStars = r.numberOfStars;
       break;
   }
   ```

   ...which will throw an NPE because you're trying to set the value of a property, `reviewText`, on `null`. You'd need to create a `Review` (or use the one passed in, depending on the API design and whether it's mutable).

   If your `Review` were immutable (can't be changed once created), which it isn't, we could safely use the instance passed in:

   ```
   if(this.reviews[i] == null) {
       this.reviews[i] = r;
       break;
   }
   ```

   But since it's mutable (can be changed), we need to create our own (presumably):

   ```
   if(this.reviews[i] == null) {
       this.reviews[i] = new Review(r.reviewText, r.numberOfStars);
       break;
   }
   ```

   There, I'm passing discrete arguments to the `Review` constructor; I'd rather add a copy constructor to `Review` and then do this:

   ```
   if(this.reviews[i] == null) {
       this.reviews[i] = new Review(r);
       break;
   }
   ```
2. `addReview` just silently fails if the array is full. You'll want to either loudly fail :-) or create a new array that's larger, copy the old array over to it, and then add to the end.

   An array may not be the ideal choice here, you might want to look at using a `List<Review>` instead (which you can initialize with `ArrayList<Review>` or `LinkedList<Review>`, whatever suits). It would be much simpler. But I don't know the design constraints.

---

Side note: Your `Review` has public fields. Typically in Java that's considered not-best-practice; consider using private fields and accessor methods instead.

Comment: ***sigh*** If you see `this.reviews[i].reviewText = new Review` in the above, hit refresh.

Comment: "Your Review is immutable" no it is not, the fields are public

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: OMG, I totally missed those `public` modifiers! Yikes.

Comment: For a complete highlight of why it doesn't work, you should also cover what happens when the array is full, i.e. the fact that the "add" will be *silently ignored!*

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you Andreas, will do and make this a CW, I'm clearly not firing on all cylinders here.

Comment: For the extra bonus, adopt [@ajb's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335230/setter-methods-for-arrays/39335267?noredirect=1#comment66001923_39335230) and suggest using `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Andreas: Heh, I didn't see that comment, but did just add a note about `List` at the end.